# How can i add animation (like fadeIn and fadeOut) in Angular (with ngx-owl-carousel-o)?

Tags: angular

i have try this but it seem doesn't work.

```
customOptions: OwlOptions = {
    loop: true,
    mouseDrag: true,
    touchDrag: true,
    pullDrag: false,
    dots: false,
    autoplay: true,
    animateIn: 'fadeIn',
    animateOut: 'fadeOut',
    autoplaySpeed: 800,
    autoplayTimeout: 5000,
    navSpeed: 700,
    navText: ['>', '<'],
    nav: false
  };
```

and html

```
<owl-carousel-o [options]="customOptions" #owlCar   (translated)="getPassedData($event)">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let slide of sliderData.data">
    <ng-template
      carouselSlide
      [id]="slide._id"
    >
      <!-- <img [ngClass]="{'slider-img': true}" [src]="slide.image" [alt]="slide.title"> -->
      <div
        [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + slide.image + ')', 'background-size': 'auto'}" [ngClass]="{slider_img: isFavorite}"

        fxFlex fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="10px" fxLayoutAlign="center"
      >
        <div [ngClass]="{ slider_text: isFavorite }">
          <h3>Just test</h3>
          <p>Just Test</p>
        <a href="#" mat-raised-button><span>Explore Now</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </ng-container>
</owl-carousel-o>
```

angular.json

"styles": [
              "node_modules/ngx-owl-carousel-o/lib/styles/prebuilt-themes/owl.carousel.min.css",
              "node_modules/ngx-owl-carousel-o/lib/styles/prebuilt-themes/owl.theme.default.min.css",
              "node_modules/animate.css/animate.min.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

animate.css had breaking changes in 4.1.0 that requires you to restructure the name of your classes.

Ex:

```js
{
  // ...
  animateOut: 'animate__animated animate__slideOutDown',
  animateIn: 'animate__animated animate__flipInX',
 // ...
}
```

https://github.com/vitalii-andriiovskyi/ngx-owl-carousel-o/issues/104#issuecomment-662594484

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27938074)

Comment: Thanks, kinda new to this but want to help where I can :)